# Java: How custom DI configuration works for WARs and EARs

Tags: java, dependency-injection, war, ear

I have written a `Bootstrapper` class that reads an XML file from the classpath and can be used as a lightweight dependency injector by other classes at runtime:

```
<!-- myAppConfig.xml -->
<appConfig>
    <environment runningOn="LOCAL" host="localhost.example.com" system="Windows 7"/>
</appConfig>

public class Bootstrapper
{
    private String runningOn = "Unknown";
    private String host = "Unknown";
    private String system = "Unknown";

    public Bootstrapper(final String appConfigFileName)
    {
        setRunningOn(extractRunningOn(appConfigFileName));
        setHost(extractHost(appConfigFileName));
        setSystem(extractSystem(appConfigFileName));
    }

    public String getHost()
    {
        return host;
    }

    // Rest of class ommitted for brevity...
}

// Then in an executable JAR's main method:
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper("myAppConfig.xml");

    // Prints: "This app is running on the localhost.example.com server node."
    System.out.println("This app is running on the " +
        bootstrapper.getHost() + " server node.");
}
```

In this sense `appConfig` and `Bootstrapper` kind of serve as **ultra** lightweight "DI" mechanisms.

**What I'm wondering is: how do I translate this design to a WAR's web.xml and an EAR's server.xml?**

Whereas in an executable JAR, the `main` method explicitly instantiates a `Bootstrapper` which can then be interrogated for its fields/properties, in a WAR/EAR everything is defined in an XML file (`web.xml`/`server.xml`) without a single "entry point". So in a WAR or EAR, if I had multiple classes that each needed to know what the local host name was, I would have to keep instantiating the same `Bootstrapper` over and over again, passing it the same `myAppConfig.xml` each time.

I'm wondering if there's a way to configure web.xml and server.xml to instantiate a `Bootstrapper` on startup/deployment, and to automatically inject/populate my dependent classes right then and there (or, at the very least, to give each dependent class *access* to the global/singleton `Bootstrapper` defined in the XML file).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For a war (and an ear since it will contain a war) project you could use a ServletContextListener to instantiate your Bootstrapper.

A good example of how to use a ServletContextListener is [here](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/).

However if you are using Java EE 6 then a better way to do this would be to use an EJB 3.1 Singleton and some CDI.

```
import javax.ejb.Singleton
import javax.ejb.Startup
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped

@Singleton         // EJB 3.1 Singleton
@Startup           // Telling the container to eagerly load on startup
@ApplicationScoped // CDI Scope
public class Bootstrapper {

    private String host = "Unknown";

    @PostConstruct
    public void readConfiguration() {
        // ... load your xml file
    }

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }
}
```

Using the above you can now inject this Bootstrapper bean within most of the EE 6 ecosystem with a simple @Inject or @EJB annotation.